# Error: Data truncated for column 'lat'

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

i try to save place information of form into the WAMP server database. i can add a record to table with `insert` function in phpmyadmin page. 
but when i `insert` coordinate in form and submit this to save information into the database i see this error:

```
Data truncated for column 'lat' at row 1
```

i define my table with this columns:

```
place_id: int(10)
p_name: varchar(50)
lat: float(30,27)
lng: float(30,27)
addr: varchar(100)
tel: int(12)
category: varchar(15)
description: varchar(200)
```

one of coordinate that i try to save is:

```
(47.61304128921687,-122.29001998901367)
```

that lat is `float(16,14)`
what is can be wrong in code except that length of data is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a nonstandard syntax to declare your FLOAT columns.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/floating-point-types.html

Try just declaring those columns as `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`. The numbers after the parentheses don't affect the storage of your numbers, just the formatting.

By the way, 47.61304128921687 is masquerading as a north-south position with a precision of about 1.1 nanometers.  It's self-evidently not that precise.  If you're working with commercial-grade GPS, FLOAT is plenty of precision for the data you're handling.  If you know the difference between UTM and Lambert projections, DOUBLE will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

14 decimal places is unrealistic. Even [**5 decimal places**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) = 0.00001 deg = 1.1132 metres (at equator) is probably the not achievable,

**Latitude**

FLOAT(7,5) is able to store any value with three digits and five decimals, so values that can be stored in the lat column range from -99.99999 to 99.99999 (Maximum values) +90 -90   (Real Max values)

**Longitude**

FLOAT(8,5) is able to store any value with three digits and five decimals, so values that can be stored in the lng column range from -999.99999 to 999.99999 (Maximum values) +180 -180   (Real Max values)